# MySQL - table join duplicate data

Tags: mysql, join

Im trying to join 3 different tables into a single for readability and means you dont have to load seperate tables to view the content

these 3 tables contain different values all regarding the same entity (cat)

within these tables there are multiple entries regarding a single cat to follow normalization and remove multi value attributes.

these are the table structures:

```
CATMEDICAL( Chip_ID, Med_His ) VALUES( %s, %s)
CATDIET( Chip_ID, Diet_Req ) VALUES( %s, %s)
CATREQ( Chip_ID, Add_Req ) VALUES( %s, %s)
```

I am using the following script to join these tables:

```
SELECT 
  CATINFO.Chip_ID AS Cat, 
  CATDIET.Diet_Req AS Diet, 
  CATMEDICAL.Med_his AS Med, 
  CATREQ.Add_Req AS Req 
  FROM CATINFO 
  INNER JOIN CATDIET ON CATINFO.Chip_ID = CATDIET.Chip_ID 
  INNER JOIN CATMEDICAL ON CATINFO.Chip_ID = CATMEDICAL.Chip_ID 
  INNER JOIN CATREQ ON CATINFO.Chip_ID = CATREQ.chip_ID
```

This scripts executes fine, the problem im having is that duplicate date is presented.

for example cat3 has multiple entries in all 3 tables meaning the resulting joined table has multiple indexes for cat3,

```
'3', 'nut allergy', 'allergy emergency', 'left alone'
'3', 'nut allergy', 'allergy emergency', 'tv on'
'3', 'nut allergy', 'hip surgery', 'left alone'
'3', 'nut allergy', 'hip surgery', 'tv on'
```

is there a way to remove the duplicate results/index's and join them into a single line just for viewing coherence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY CATINFO.Chip_ID, CATDIET.Diet_Req` and use `GROUP_CONCAT()` like this:

```
SELECT 
  CATINFO.Chip_ID AS Cat, 
  CATDIET.Diet_Req AS Diet, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CATMEDICAL.Med_his) AS Med, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CATREQ.Add_Req) AS Req 
FROM CATINFO 
INNER JOIN CATDIET ON CATINFO.Chip_ID = CATDIET.Chip_ID 
INNER JOIN CATMEDICAL ON CATINFO.Chip_ID = CATMEDICAL.Chip_ID 
INNER JOIN CATREQ ON CATINFO.Chip_ID = CATREQ.chip_ID
GROUP BY CATINFO.Chip_ID, CATDIET.Diet_Req
```

This way you get 1 row for each combination of `CATINFO.Chip_ID` and, `CATDIET.Diet_Req` and the other columns as comma separated lists:

```
'3' | 'nut allergy' | 'allergy emergency','hip surgery' | 'left alone','tv on'
```

Comment: Thanks dude, you have really helped me out a lot :)